# Creating a loop within a UserForm

Tags: excel, vba, loops, userform

this is a continuation of my previous question... 
I'm trying to create a user form that will go through a list on a worksheet (TESTER). The form should display the first row of data from the list. User will also be able to select one of two options Active or ITW. Finally, the user is free to add additional comments.

This is where I'm running into trouble, once the user clicks Add, the values from the form should populate the next blank row in a separate sheet (pasteHere). I have no issues with the form displaying the next line of data on the list, but I don't know how to create a loop that will allow me to find the next blank row after clicking the add button. At the moment, I've only initialized `j` as 1. And every time I click add, it will paste on the first row in the pasteHere worksheet.

```
Sub addBtn_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

Dim j As Long

j = 1 'how can I loop this part

Set pasteSheet = Application.Worksheets("pasteHere")

pasteSheet.Cells(j, j) = ric
pasteSheet.Cells(j, j + 2) = name
pasteSheet.Cells(j, j + 4) = valueUSD

pasteSheet.Cells(j + 1, j) = dstr

i = i + 1
j = j + 2

UserForm1_Initialize

End Sub
```

Would appreciate any help here. Full code below:

```
Public valueUSD, name, ric, dstr, sitchStr, pStr As String
Public i, lRow As Long

Sub UserForm1_Initialize()

If Worksheets("pasteHere").Range("A1") = "" Then
    i = 2
End If

activeCheck.Value = False
itwCheck.Value = False
TextBox2.Value = ""

ric = Worksheets("Tester").Range("H" & i)
name = Worksheets("Tester").Range("B" & i)
valueUSD = Worksheets("Tester").Range("C" & i)
sitchStr = ""
dstr = ""

pStr = ric & "   " & name & "   " & valueUSD & "   "

UserForm1.Label1.Caption = pStr

End Sub
Sub activeCheck_Change()

    If activeCheck.Value = True Then
        sitchStr = sitchStr + activeCheck.Caption
    Else
        sitchStr = ""
    End If

End Sub

Sub itwCheck_Change()

    If activeCheck.Value = False And itwCheck.Value = True Then
        sitchStr = sitchStr + itwCheck.Caption
    ElseIf activeCheck.Value = True And itwCheck.Value = True Then
        MsgBox ("You can only be active OR ITW")
    End If

End Sub

Sub TextBox2_Change()
    dstr = sitchStr & ", " & TextBox2.Value
End Sub

Sub addBtn_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

Dim j As Long

j = 1 'how can I loop this part

Set pasteSheet = Application.Worksheets("pasteHere")

pasteSheet.Cells(j, j) = ric
pasteSheet.Cells(j, j + 2) = name
pasteSheet.Cells(j, j + 4) = valueUSD

pasteSheet.Cells(j + 1, j) = dstr

i = i + 1
j = j + 2

UserForm1_Initialize

End Sub

Sub skipBtn_Click()
    i = i + 1
    UserForm1_Initialize
End Sub

Sub exitBtn_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: Declare `j` at the top of the module to make it public to all procedures in the module. And delete `j=1`. Or write `If j=0 Then j=1` so each time it reads that line it will not set j to 1 unless it's the first time run from opening the file. Also keep in mind that as soon as the user closes the file `j` will be destroyed and start over again.

Comment: Thank you! This worked really well. 

I was wondering if you would be able to help with a second question, with regards to my variable "i". My variable pStr should show ric, name, valueUSD values that are pulled from the worksheet and dependent on i. 

Upon 1st initialization, UserForm1.Label1.Caption shows up as "Label1" instead of pStr. How do I have i start from 2?

Comment: Where you declare that `i=2` add an else block to say `i=1`. Otherwise, it will equal 0 by default.

Comment: Thanks Scott, do you know why upon first Initialization, my Label1.Caption is still displaying Label1? It will only change to display cell values if I click skip.

Comment: try adding `UserForm1.Repaint` to see the change